# How to use AppleScript to let Arcobat automatically convert PDF to image（JPEG）

Tags: automation, applescript, adobe

I want to use AppleScript to let Arcobat automatically save the PDF as JPEG. The operation is as follows. It is only through the AppleScript code. Please give pointers to the master. 
                                            Thank you very much.
[Acrobat saves PDF as JPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMHRA.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acrobat is widely scriptable.

You have to use the `save` command with the parameter `using conversion "com.adobe.acrobat.jpeg"`

This code saves the active document to the desktop folder as JPG named `test.jpg`

```
set filePath to (path to desktop as text) & "test.jpg"
tell application "Adobe Acrobat Pro"
    save active doc to filePath using conversion "com.adobe.acrobat.jpeg"
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful answer, it solved my problem perfectly, thank you again, I tried to use save, but failed, because I don't know the existence of "com.adobe.acrobat.jpeg", if you don't mind Can you tell me where I can find Acrobat's applescript guide, because I don't fully understand the dictionary features provided by Apple itself.

Comment: As far as I know there is no Adobe AppleScript Guide. I just read the dictionary. The `save` command has a parameter `using` whose argument is of type `Conversion`. With `get conversions` you get a list of all possible formats.